# RCP for creating standalone application, later converted to plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an standalone GUI for our in-house tool. After it has matured enough, it is supposed to be integrated into Eclipse as a plugin.

I am a newcomer to Java world. I have read about RCP. Is this is correct use case scenario for RCP? If yes, can I use SWT views in a RCP application/plugin?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this is correct use case scenario for RCP?

Yes, RCP is a good fit. You can use the same plugin for providing functionality both in Eclipse and in your standalone application.

> If yes, can I use SWT views in a RCP application/plugin?

Yes, of course. Until the latest version of RCP (e4) you could *only* use SWT for GUI (of course, Swing/JavaFX/etc. can be integrated with SWT).

Answer (score 2):

When you develop an Eclipse RCP based application, you in fact develop a number of plug-ins. If you play by a specific set of limited rules, then your plug-in can run unaltered as part of an RCP application and as part of the larger Eclipse IDE.

(One can easily argue that the IDE is "just" a very large RCP application. The IDE is based on the Eclipse Platform of which Eclipse RCP is just a small sub-set...)

I would recommend two books for your project:

- "Eclipse Rich Client Platform (2nd Edition)" by Jeff McAffer, Jean-Michel Lemieux, and Chris Aniszczyk - see [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321603788).
- "Eclipse Plug-ins (3rd Edition)" by Eric Clayberg and Dan Rubel - see [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321553462).

Where the first is more or less the bible for RCP based applications, the later gives you a lot of good examples on how to integrate into the IDE. Very advanced as times, but also very good.